How do get a dropdown of all countries in Wordpress
Is there a shorter way to get all countries populated options, instead of writing options one by one, in the following dropdown?
<select name="input-country" id="input-country"
class="form-control form-control-alternative">
<option value="">Select a country / region…</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>

Or how do get a dropdown of all countries in Wordpress?

Hey @JustSadY , are you writing that html in a PHP file?

The following custom shortcode will display a country dropdown:
// Utility function: Return an array of countries (code / name pairs)
function get_all_countries() {
    return array(
        'AF' => __('Afghanistan'),
        'AX' => __('Åland Islands'),
        'AL' => __('Albania'),
        'DZ' => __('Algeria'),
        'AS' => __('American Samoa'),
        'AD' => __('Andorra'),
        'AO' => __('Angola'),
        'AI' => __('Anguilla'),
        'AQ' => __('Antarctica'),
        'AG' => __('Antigua and Barbuda'),
        'AR' => __('Argentina'),
        'AM' => __('Armenia'),
        'AW' => __('Aruba'),
        'AU' => __('Australia'),
        'AT' => __('Austria'),
        'AZ' => __('Azerbaijan'),
        'BS' => __('Bahamas'),
        'BH' => __('Bahrain'),
        'BD' => __('Bangladesh'),
        'BB' => __('Barbados'),
        'BY' => __('Belarus'),
        'PW' => __('Belau'),
        'BE' => __('Belgium'),
        'BZ' => __('Belize'),
        'BJ' => __('Benin'),
        'BM' => __('Bermuda'),
        'BT' => __('Bhutan'),
        'BO' => __('Bolivia'),
        'BQ' => __('Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba'),
        'BA' => __('Bosnia and Herzegovina'),
        'BW' => __('Botswana'),
        'BV' => __('Bouvet Island'),
        'BR' => __('Brazil'),
        'IO' => __('British Indian Ocean Territory'),
        'BN' => __('Brunei'),
        'BG' => __('Bulgaria'),
        'BF' => __('Burkina Faso'),
        'BI' => __('Burundi'),
        'KH' => __('Cambodia'),
        'CM' => __('Cameroon'),
        'CA' => __('Canada'),
        'CV' => __('Cape Verde'),
        'KY' => __('Cayman Islands'),
        'CF' => __('Central African Republic'),
        'TD' => __('Chad'),
        'CL' => __('Chile'),
        'CN' => __('China'),
        'CX' => __('Christmas Island'),
        'CC' => __('Cocos (Keeling) Islands'),
        'CO' => __('Colombia'),
        'KM' => __('Comoros'),
        'CG' => __('Congo (Brazzaville)'),
        'CD' => __('Congo (Kinshasa)'),
        'CK' => __('Cook Islands'),
        'CR' => __('Costa Rica'),
        'HR' => __('Croatia'),
        'CU' => __('Cuba'),
        'CW' => __('Curaçao'),
        'CY' => __('Cyprus'),
        'CZ' => __('Czech Republic'),
        'DK' => __('Denmark'),
        'DJ' => __('Djibouti'),
        'DM' => __('Dominica'),
        'DO' => __('Dominican Republic'),
        'EC' => __('Ecuador'),
        'EG' => __('Egypt'),
        'SV' => __('El Salvador'),
        'GQ' => __('Equatorial Guinea'),
        'ER' => __('Eritrea'),
        'EE' => __('Estonia'),
        'SZ' => __('Eswatini'),
        'ET' => __('Ethiopia'),
        'FK' => __('Falkland Islands'),
        'FO' => __('Faroe Islands'),
        'FJ' => __('Fiji'),
        'FI' => __('Finland'),
        'FR' => __('France'),
        'GF' => __('French Guiana'),
        'PF' => __('French Polynesia'),
        'TF' => __('French Southern Territories'),
        'GA' => __('Gabon'),
        'GM' => __('Gambia'),
        'GE' => __('Georgia'),
        'DE' => __('Germany'),
        'GH' => __('Ghana'),
        'GI' => __('Gibraltar'),
        'GR' => __('Greece'),
        'GL' => __('Greenland'),
        'GD' => __('Grenada'),
        'GP' => __('Guadeloupe'),
        'GU' => __('Guam'),
        'GT' => __('Guatemala'),
        'GG' => __('Guernsey'),
        'GN' => __('Guinea'),
        'GW' => __('Guinea-Bissau'),
        'GY' => __('Guyana'),
        'HT' => __('Haiti'),
        'HM' => __('Heard Island and McDonald Islands'),
        'HN' => __('Honduras'),
        'HK' => __('Hong Kong'),
        'HU' => __('Hungary'),
        'IS' => __('Iceland'),
        'IN' => __('India'),
        'ID' => __('Indonesia'),
        'IR' => __('Iran'),
        'IQ' => __('Iraq'),
        'IE' => __('Ireland'),
        'IM' => __('Isle of Man'),
        'IL' => __('Israel'),
        'IT' => __('Italy'),
        'CI' => __('Ivory Coast'),
        'JM' => __('Jamaica'),
        'JP' => __('Japan'),
        'JE' => __('Jersey'),
        'JO' => __('Jordan'),
        'KZ' => __('Kazakhstan'),
        'KE' => __('Kenya'),
        'KI' => __('Kiribati'),
        'KW' => __('Kuwait'),
        'KG' => __('Kyrgyzstan'),
        'LA' => __('Laos'),
        'LV' => __('Latvia'),
        'LB' => __('Lebanon'),
        'LS' => __('Lesotho'),
        'LR' => __('Liberia'),
        'LY' => __('Libya'),
        'LI' => __('Liechtenstein'),
        'LT' => __('Lithuania'),
        'LU' => __('Luxembourg'),
        'MO' => __('Macao'),
        'MG' => __('Madagascar'),
        'MW' => __('Malawi'),
        'MY' => __('Malaysia'),
        'MV' => __('Maldives'),
        'ML' => __('Mali'),
        'MT' => __('Malta'),
        'MH' => __('Marshall Islands'),
        'MQ' => __('Martinique'),
        'MR' => __('Mauritania'),
        'MU' => __('Mauritius'),
        'YT' => __('Mayotte'),
        'MX' => __('Mexico'),
        'FM' => __('Micronesia'),
        'MD' => __('Moldova'),
        'MC' => __('Monaco'),
        'MN' => __('Mongolia'),
        'ME' => __('Montenegro'),
        'MS' => __('Montserrat'),
        'MA' => __('Morocco'),
        'MZ' => __('Mozambique'),
        'MM' => __('Myanmar'),
        'NA' => __('Namibia'),
        'NR' => __('Nauru'),
        'NP' => __('Nepal'),
        'NL' => __('Netherlands'),
        'NC' => __('New Caledonia'),
        'NZ' => __('New Zealand'),
        'NI' => __('Nicaragua'),
        'NE' => __('Niger'),
        'NG' => __('Nigeria'),
        'NU' => __('Niue'),
        'NF' => __('Norfolk Island'),
        'KP' => __('North Korea'),
        'MK' => __('North Macedonia'),
        'MP' => __('Northern Mariana Islands'),
        'NO' => __('Norway'),
        'OM' => __('Oman'),
        'PK' => __('Pakistan'),
        'PS' => __('Palestinian Territory'),
        'PA' => __('Panama'),
        'PG' => __('Papua New Guinea'),
        'PY' => __('Paraguay'),
        'PE' => __('Peru'),
        'PH' => __('Philippines'),
        'PN' => __('Pitcairn'),
        'PL' => __('Poland'),
        'PT' => __('Portugal'),
        'PR' => __('Puerto Rico'),
        'QA' => __('Qatar'),
        'RE' => __('Reunion'),
        'RO' => __('Romania'),
        'RU' => __('Russia'),
        'RW' => __('Rwanda'),
        'ST' => __('São Tomé and Príncipe'),
        'BL' => __('Saint Barthélemy'),
        'SH' => __('Saint Helena'),
        'KN' => __('Saint Kitts and Nevis'),
        'LC' => __('Saint Lucia'),
        'SX' => __('Saint Martin (Dutch part)'),
        'MF' => __('Saint Martin (French part)'),
        'PM' => __('Saint Pierre and Miquelon'),
        'VC' => __('Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'),
        'WS' => __('Samoa'),
        'SM' => __('San Marino'),
        'SA' => __('Saudi Arabia'),
        'SN' => __('Senegal'),
        'RS' => __('Serbia'),
        'SC' => __('Seychelles'),
        'SL' => __('Sierra Leone'),
        'SG' => __('Singapore'),
        'SK' => __('Slovakia'),
        'SI' => __('Slovenia'),
        'SB' => __('Solomon Islands'),
        'SO' => __('Somalia'),
        'ZA' => __('South Africa'),
        'GS' => __('South Georgia/Sandwich Islands'),
        'KR' => __('South Korea'),
        'SS' => __('South Sudan'),
        'ES' => __('Spain'),
        'LK' => __('Sri Lanka'),
        'SD' => __('Sudan'),
        'SR' => __('Suriname'),
        'SJ' => __('Svalbard and Jan Mayen'),
        'SE' => __('Sweden'),
        'CH' => __('Switzerland'),
        'SY' => __('Syria'),
        'TW' => __('Taiwan'),
        'TJ' => __('Tajikistan'),
        'TZ' => __('Tanzania'),
        'TH' => __('Thailand'),
        'TL' => __('Timor-Leste'),
        'TG' => __('Togo'),
        'TK' => __('Tokelau'),
        'TO' => __('Tonga'),
        'TT' => __('Trinidad and Tobago'),
        'TN' => __('Tunisia'),
        'TR' => __('Turkey'),
        'TM' => __('Turkmenistan'),
        'TC' => __('Turks and Caicos Islands'),
        'TV' => __('Tuvalu'),
        'UG' => __('Uganda'),
        'UA' => __('Ukraine'),
        'AE' => __('United Arab Emirates'),
        'GB' => __('United Kingdom (UK)'),
        'US' => __('United States (US)'),
        'UM' => __('United States (US) Minor Outlying Islands'),
        'UY' => __('Uruguay'),
        'UZ' => __('Uzbekistan'),
        'VU' => __('Vanuatu'),
        'VA' => __('Vatican'),
        'VE' => __('Venezuela'),
        'VN' => __('Vietnam'),
        'VG' => __('Virgin Islands (British)'),
        'VI' => __('Virgin Islands (US)'),
        'WF' => __('Wallis and Futuna'),
        'EH' => __('Western Sahara'),
        'YE' => __('Yemen'),
        'ZM' => __('Zambia'),
        'ZW' => __('Zimbabwe'),
    );
}

// Shortcode that displays a country dropdown
add_shortcode  ('countries', 'countries_dropdown' ); 
function countries_dropdown() {
   $html = '<select name="input-country" id="input-country" class="form-control form-control-alternative">
   <option value="">'.__('Select a country / region…').'</option>';

    foreach ( get_all_countries() as $code => $name ) {
        $html .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $code, $name );
    }
    return $html . '</select>';
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
Usage:

In WordPress Post/page Editor, and some widgets: [countries];
In PHP files: echo do_shortcode('[countries]');


Here's an example of how you might do it in PHP using a custom array of countries:
<?php
// Array of countries with their ISO Alpha-2 codes
$countries = array(
    "AF" => "Afghanistan",
    "AX" => "Åland Islands",
    "AL" => "Albania",
    // ... Add all other countries
);

// Function to generate the options for the select dropdown
function generate_country_options($countries) {
    $options = '';
    foreach ($countries as $code => $name) {
        $options .= "<option value=\"$code\">$name</option>\n";
    }
    return $options;
}
?>

<select name="input-country" id="input-country" class="form-control form- 
control-alternative">
    <option value="">Select a country / region…</option>
    <?php echo generate_country_options($countries); ?>
</select>

In this example, you create an associative array $countries where each key is a country's ISO Alpha-2 code and each value is the country's name. The generate_country_options function loops through this array and builds the option tags for the dropdown.
